# How to access Json Response

Tags: php, jquery, json, file-upload

Here  is my code for uploading the files to my server.

```
$(function () {
$('#phy_fileupload').fileupload({
    autoUpload: true,
    add: function (e, data) {
        $('body').append('<p class="upl">Uploading...</p>')
        data.submit();
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#phy_progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
             $('.upl').remove();
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo("#phy_files");
        });
    }
});
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="phy_progress">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
                                                <input id="phy_fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="<?php echo site_url('admin/upload/'); ?>" multiple>

<div class="files" id="phy_files"></div>
```

It works very well, uploads the picture and send json in response which i can see in FIREBUG.

Here is Response of one uploaded file.

```
{"files":[{"name":"2013-06-20_1235UQn5gm5SRUPzbA.png","size":29381,"url":"http:\/\/files\/2013-06-20_1235UQn5gm5SRUPzbA.png","thumbnail_url":"http:\/\/files\/thumbnail\/2013-06-20_1235UQn5gm5SRUPzbA.png","delete_url":"http:\/\/localhost\/mark\/?file=2013-06-20_1235UQn5gm5SRUPzbA.png","delete_type":"DELETE"}]}
```

Now the issue is that it adds the name of file in the div (#phy_files) (i.e 2013-06-20_1235.png), how ever I want to add the new file name which was uploaded to the server (i.e) 2013-06-20_1235UQn5gm5SRUPzbA.png. Now I spent all day to try to access this response of Json,  but apparently either i have been looking at the wrong end or I'm completely lost, I have so far no idea how can i access this response.

Any help would really be appreciated. Please let me know if you don't understand what i have written here, I'm more than happy to explain it again if required. Thank you.

In Short:

what the issue is that the file being uploaded is named let say 'file.png', on server its name is changed to 'filexyzserdsdf.png', now i want the response file name to be written in the my div (#phy_files) , but it is writing 'file.png ' instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now its getting clear... ok you should do this then :

```
done: function (e, data) {
    var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data.result);
    $.each(res.files, function (index, file) {
         $('.upl').remove();
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo("#phy_files");
    });
}
```

Comment: IT WORKED :) Thank you so much Reyaner. I really do appreciate your help:) spent whole day on that .... but i can say at last it worked  :) Thank you.

Comment: no problem sir! :)
just to explain, the result is a string. so you have to parse it to a JSON object... selam!

Answer (score 0):

so if you console.log data, what is in the log=?

```
done: function (e, data) {
console.log(data);
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
             $('.upl').remove();
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo("#phy_files");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you reyaner

Here is what i have after i console.log


http://screencast.com/t/DCGI7ThTkg

Comment: ok, and where did you get this from: {"files":[{"name":"2013-06-20_1235UQn5gm5SRUPzbA.png".... in your post.?
in your pic. the file.name is: 2013-06-20_1235.png...

Comment: yes the file that I uploaded has a  name: 2013-06-20_1235.png. But server script changes the uploaded file name and creates a json which is this - >  {"files":[{"name":"2013-06-20_1235UQn5gm5SRUPzbA.png".. in our response.

Comment: In this picture you can see that where does that come from: check under the heading of result.


Now here is what i get, the variable data has all information which was uploaded and result has all which was returned from server. Now how can i access the information under 'result' heading.

http://screencast.com/t/0Y0Qox6O5