# How to access json response object of data.submit() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am uploading an image by using mini-upload-form plugin. The image uploading is working fine. But I want to get ready state and other values from the response object after upload. I have tried to implement the following solution but it didn't work in my case.
[How to access Json Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320879/how-to-access-json-response)

I have displayed the response object in console.log. Console Log:

```
 Object { readyState=1, setRequestHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}
```

Following is the code, I am using in js file.

```
   // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
    var jqXHR = data.submit();
    console.log(jqXHR);
    if(jqXHR){
        var avatarpath = $('#avatarimage').attr("src");
        alert(avatarpath);
    }
```

Basically, I need to access responseText part of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve JSON data using the HTTPClient object. Within the onload callback, `this.responseText` contains the raw text response from the target URL. It is the property you should use when processing JSON or other plain text data:

```
var url = "http://example.com/json.txt";
var json;

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function() {
       // parse the retrieved data, turning it into a JavaScript object
       json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       // ...

    }
});
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
 
@ravindra when I tried this:
var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);